# Why are Python lists implemented as dynamic arrays instead of ring buffers?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, language-design, python-internals

A `list` in Python is now implemented as dynamic array of pointers, so it's not suitable for insertion and deletion at the front end. However, [ring buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) also supports O(1) indexing. It can also expand and shrink like a dynamic array to support O(1) amortized insertion and deletion at both end. Why didn't CPython choose this implementation, or what's the main disadvantage of it?

Comment: My guess would be that lists in Python can also be used as stacks and a stack is less when implemented in a ring buffer.

Comment: [collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Comment: lists, tuples and dicts are the basic data structures of python, these are heavily optimized for the standard use-cases and `collections.deque` is generally not as fast as the array-like-list. So probably just because of performance (that's no definite answer, just a guess).

Comment: This is not primarily opinion-based. He didn't ask what the _best ever_ implementation of a list is, he asked what the factors were behind the decision to use a non-circular array in Python's default list. This can be productively answered with objectivity, through pros and cons, using computer science knowledge and historical records. I vote to reopen.

Comment: @slezica I think the question "Will such a list supporting insertion and deletion at both end be more beginner-friendly" is opinion-based. Maybe that's not applicable to the other parts of the question. However the fact that there are lots of "subquestions" in this question makes it a bit "too broad" as well. But that's just my opinion (so also "opinion-based").

Comment: Thanks, I've modified my question to be more objective.

Comment: @Chris_Rands But `collections.deque` is not a general-purpose list type, and it doesn't support O(1) indexing.

Comment: @JialinSong I voted to re-open and now it is open

Answer (score 1):

With a ring buffer, you'd need some index transformation on every access, unless the start position happens to be at index 0. But even then, you'd have to check for the start position to be 0.

O(1) just means that the operation has fixed cost, but it doesn't tell you whether that fixed cost is high or low. With a dynamic array, the cost of accessing an element by index is as low as it can get: check the range, then access the item.

The Python FAQ on the topic doesn't discuss alternative implementation techniques, but it does mention accessing elements by index as an optimization target:
https://docs.python.org/3/faq/design.html#how-are-lists-implemented-in-cpython